# Trying to understand .bashrc, env, and export

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, environment-variables, bashrc

Disclaimer: Using bash.

I just need some confirmation / correction on my understanding of these things:

1. `env` is basically displaying the current environmental variables that are accessible to my current session AND any child sessions (such as if I were to `bash` into a child session).
2. If I were to set a new variable such as `MYMESSAGE="hello world!"` then it would only be visible to the session in which I created it. If I went into a child session, I would not be able to, for example, `echo $MYMESSAGE`.
3. I can `export MYMESSAGE="hello world!"` though to make it accessible to child sessions. `export` is the same as adding it to whatever `env` is pulling up.
4. However, just because you `export` something, it won't stick if you happen to close out your sessions and restart the terminal. Edit `.bashrc` in your `/home/username/` directory and add any new environmental variables there, since this script is run on login.

Is my understanding correct so far?

Furthermore, I don't fully understand where the details of `env` comes from. Is the list of environmental variables all stored in some file and then edited/appended to by `.bashrc`? I'm just trying to understand how all of this works.

Comment: Note that using `.bashrc` is only valid, as long as you use `bash` as your login shell. It might happen that you start preferring some other shell in the future and would then need to modify the respective `rc`-file.

Comment: To get a full understanding of which file does what, consider reading: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DotFiles

Comment: Short answer to question #5: environment variables are stored in the memory of *each process* — that's why it's possible for each process to have a different environment.  See [To whom do environment variables belong?](http://superuser.com/q/932150/354511) for some more information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You basically got it right, however a few extra points...

There are several "start-up files" bash may run - some for backwards compatibility with the bourne-shell (sh), other depending on how you started bash:  Did you log-in to X?  Did you log-in to a TTY?  Did you start `bash` in another (bash-)shell?  Is bash running as a script (non-interactive)?  Thus .bashrc is not *always* run, nor may it be the only start-up file.  However, it's a good idea to "source" (read and execute) .bashrc in the other start-up files too, so the content of your .bashrc is always added.  Use `man bash` and look especially on the part about how bash starts... the FILES-section also list the files bash uses, including all start-up files.  For a more in-depth, try `info bash`.

In addition to you own start-up files, there are corresponding "default" global start-up files in /etc - these are typically read/executed by `bash` before your own start-up files.  There also other programs that defines their own environment-variables in addition to those defined by bash,which may complement or even override those set by bash.  Of particular note is X (the GUI), since it will set-up two *different* sets of environments, depending on whether X is started manually (with `xinit` or `startx`) from a VT, or is started by a "display manager" (eg. `xdm` or `kdm`) so you can log-in directly into X (X is started when you boot, and you got a dialog-box for username/password in X).

But before `bash`, `X` or any other programs starts, much of the environment - environment-variables - you'll be using, will have been set-up, for example by the `login` command.  Much of this you can find in /etc/login.defs and other configuration-files.  For example, the PATH-variable will be set-up - and will differ depending on whether you're root or a normal user.

So if you look at the various files and scripts that are ran as part of the boot, init and log-in process; you'll find most of all the variables you can list with `env`.  Some however - like `CWD` (current working directory) - are set (and updated) automatically by the shell (bash) itself.

When you run a command, what happen is that bash use a system call called fork().  `bash` basically makes an identical copy of itself, with the exception that the child gets a new PID (Process ID) and that it's PPID (Parent PID) is that of it's "mother".  Else they're identical - even including the environment-variables... assuming the variable in question was made inheritable by first `export`ing it.  You now got two copies of `bash`.  Then another system-call -exec() - is used, which basically replaces the bash-program "in memory" for the child bash-process, with another program - for example with `ls`, `ps` or `mutt` (whatever you typed)... but the environment-variables remains, so the new program inherits it's environment from `bash`.  This child now controls your terminal (unless you put the command in the background with &) until it terminates, while your original bash-shell (basically) sleeps.  When the command terminates, you return to your original `bash`-shell, which is ready for another command.

Answer (score 2):

The environment is not passed via a file but via the stack of newly created processes and the method to achieve this is to pass the environment to the `exec()` system call.

- `env` is an external command (in contrary to shell built in commands) and for this reason, `env` only prints variables that are `exported` from the shell.
- `set` on the other side lists all shell variables. Some of them are exported.
- `export` lists the shell variables that are exported by the shell.

BTW:

- `.bashrc` is not run by login shells, but rather by every interactive (bash) shell. Other shells have other names for this feature. `ksh` uses `.kshrc` and the Bourne Shell uses `.shrc`.
- `.profile` is run by login shells. This file is shared between all Bourne Shell compatible shelle.

Comment: I am a noob so I may need a slightly dumbed-down explanation. I don't know the difference between an "external command" and "built-in shell command." I also don't understand how `env` is only "exported" variables since I can type `env` and see a whole list of stuff without having typed anything like `export MYMESSAGE="hello world"`. Would you be able to define your terms (or clarify if my understanding is off/inaccurate/imprecise)

Comment: I also don't know what the intended differentiation is between `.bashrc` being run by "login shells" versus "interactive (bash) shells". I'm not physically opening/running `.bashrc` interactively or anything. I assumed it runs by itself whenever I login to the shell/terminal/whatever the right terminology is. I know other shells have other features, but for now I'm referring to bash (I updated the OP to reflect this).

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding is correct.

Your /home/username/.bashrc appends (or overwrites) the settings in /etc/bash.bashrc

There are also some relevant settings in /etc/profile, and you can have a /home/username/.profile but these exist primarily for historical compatibility reasons.  (They are an artifact of the Bourne shell, which Bash is based upon.)