# Rationale behind persistent env variables between consecutive usages of source

Tags: bash, shell-script

**Context:**

- OS: *openSUSE Leap 15.1*
- Kernel: *Linux 4.12.14-lp151.27-default*
- shell: *GNU bash, version 4.4.23(1)-release (x86_64-suse-linux-gnu)*

**Given the following script, let's call it test.sh**:

```
#!/bin/bash -e
echo "$TEST_VAR"
```

On different runs, it returns:

`TEST_VAR=1234; source test.sh` -> **Output**: *1234*

`source test.sh ->` **Output**: *1234*

**Question:**

- Why does the value of env *TEST_VAR* persists between runs ( `env | grep -i test_var)` returns nothing also)?
- Is there any way to prevent that rather than using something like `exec bash`?
- If the previous answer is yes, is there any solution that is at least to some degree cross shell?

Thank you.

Comment: Is there a reason why you have to use `source` instead of running the script directly? That makes a difference to the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`source` (a synonym to [`.` (dot)](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#dot) will

> execute commands in the current environment

that is, it will not execute `test.sh` in a new shell with its own variables, but just run every command in it in your current shell. In particular, this makes your `#!/bin/bash -e` shebang ineffective, it's treated as a comment. If you were to change your script to

```bsh
set -e
echo "$TEST_VAR"
false
```

`source`ing it would immediately exit your interactive session because of the return code of `false`. If you are not saving the output of your current shell somewhere, any error messages will be lost by this (that's not so important for just `false`, but important to consider for real scripts). I would recommend against using `source` in combination with `set -e` to run any scripts that might fail.

`TEST_VAR=1234; source test.sh` persists the value of `TEST_VAR` because the `;` simply delimits commands, making `TEST_VAR=1234; source test.sh` the same as

```bsh
TEST_VAR=1234
source test.sh
```

That's just an assignment to `TEST_VAR` followed by a call to `source`. Since `source` runs commands in the current environment, `TEST_VAR` is available in that environment.

If the `;` wasn't there, that would change by making the assignment to `TEST_VAR` only effective for the invokation of the `source` command:

```
$ cat test.sh
#!/bin/bash -e
echo $TEST_VAR
$ TEST_VAR=1234 source test.sh
1234
$ source test.sh
```

> `env | grep -i test_var` returns nothing also

The reason for that is explained in https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/268258/4699:

> env is an external command (in contrary to shell built in commands) and for this reason, env only prints variables that are
>   exported from the shell.
>
> set on the other side lists all shell variables. Some of them are exported.
>
> export lists the shell variables that are exported by the shell.

`export` can also be used to export an already-set variable:

```
$ TEST_VAR=1234; source test.sh
1234
$ set | grep TEST
TEST_VAR=1234
$ env | grep TEST
$ export TEST_VAR
$ env | grep TEST
TEST_VAR=1234
```

Comment: thanks for the `set` tip ... makes sense now. Thank you for thoroughly explaining it.

Answer (score 2):

Using `source` or `.` on a script will run it in the current shell's environment.

This means that any shell variables available in the current shell will also be available in the dot-script (the script being sourced). It also means that the `#!`-line of your script will be totally ignored.

The commands that you show sets a variable, `TEST_VAR`, to some value.  Then you source you dot-script, which will have access to that shell variable, since it's sourced, so it prints its value.

Then you source the same dot-script again.  Since the shell variable hasn't ben explicitly `unset` since you last sourced the script, the value is printed again.

You get no output from your `env`+`grep` pipeline because you have no *environment* variable matching that pattern.  Note that `TEST_VAR` is never exported to the environment, it is strictly a shell variable and will therefore not be inherited by child processes (e.g. `env`).

If you run your script as an ordinary script, i.e. through making it executable with `chmod +x test.sh` and then doing `./test.sh`, you will notice that the value of the `TEST_VAR` variable in the script is empty.  This is due to the script not having access to the calling shell's shell variables, and there's no environment variable called `TEST_VAR` in the current environment (just like there wasn't for your `env`+`grep` pipeline).

You can import the value of `TEST_VAR` into your script as an environment variable, either by exporting the existing shell variable using `export TEST_VAR`, or by starting your script like

```
TEST_VAR=$TEST_VAR ./test.sh
```

or

```
env TEST_VAR="$TEST_VAR" ./test.sh
```